# Ajax dynamic dropdownlist issue

Tags: php, ajax

[image]I write these script in these i fetch the data from database using ajax with the use of model and controller ,and i get the data perfectly.
   But in the dropdownlist i get the these type of data.
    Example:3Y
            4M
            9Y
    Instead of Y i want to print "YEAR" and instead of M i want to print "MONTH" in my dropdownlist value what i do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $.ajax({

            url:'index.php?option=com_subscription&view=configuration&task=configuration.subscriptionTime',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var j = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#jform_PlanId').empty(); 
                    document.getElementById('jform_PlanId').innerHTML = '<option value="">Select Limit</option>';

                    $.each(j,function(i,iteam){
                        var div_data="<option value="+iteam.subscription_billing_type+""+iteam.subscription_billing_frquency+">"+iteam.subscription_billing_type+" "+iteam.subscription_billing_frquency+"</option>";
                        $(div_data).appendTo('#jform_PlanId');


                    });
            }
     });
  });
   </script>
```

Comment: just php preg_replace or string replace Y with Year M with month

Comment: How to use it in my code?

Comment: Can you update and put the result Json?

Comment: i upload a pic.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a String concatenation like this:

```
var year = iteam.subscription_billing_frquency.concat("EAR");
var div_data="<option value="+iteam.subscription_billing_type+""+iteam.subscription_billing_frquency+">"+iteam.subscription_billing_type+" "+year+"</option>";
```

And do the same with month and day.

Comment: This doesn't change his Y and M into Year and Month like he is asking.

Comment: @clearshot66 i've changed the year one and i don't know if you saw that i wrote "And do the same with month and day.".